# Mocha js before hook and require not executing properly

Tags: node.js, mongodb, unit-testing, mocha.js

I am writing unit tests for a piece for a project, the database module is separate (it sets up connection to the database and has bulk insertion method). The code in my unit test file is as follows:

```
var database = require('./db.js');  //once the database is connected there is a log saying connected to the database 
var Data = database.model;  //module export for the model 

before(function(){
    
    console.log("We are in the before hook");
    for(var i = 1; i <= 10; i++){

      var startDate = new Date(2016,1,1,0,0,0,0);
      var endDate = new Date(2016,1,1,1,0,0,0);

      var data = test_data.genIncreasing('Watch_'+i , startDate.getTime(), endDate.getTime() , 2000, 9); //will get around 3600 points
      console.log('Inserting ' + data.length + ' datapoints into database');  
      database.bulkInsert(data, function(err, data){
          if(err){
            Should.fail('Could not insert data into data base');
          }else{
            console.log('Inserted Watch_' + i + ' data into database');
          }
      });
     }
});
```

Now in my console I am expecting to see

> Mongoose default connection open to DB-URI

followed by

> We are in the before hook
>
> Inserting 1800 datapoints into database
>
> Inserting 1800 datapoints into database [10 times]

But I get

> We are in the before hook
>
> Inserting 1800 datapoints into database
>
> Inserting 1800 datapoints into database [10 times]

Followed by

> Mongoose default connection open to: DB_URI

I did a bit of searching and found out requires are suppose to be synchronous and so are mocha unit tests. What am I missing here? Can you give me an insight into what is happening?

Comment: I am assuming your before is inside `describe`?

Comment: Nope it is outside but I get the same results when I put it inside a describe

Comment: May be the connection in the `db.js` is lazy?

Comment: Sorry what do you mean when you say db.js is lazy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> May be the connection in the db.js is lazy? – [Petr Mar 28 at 21:56](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36271742/mocha-js-before-hook-and-require-not-executing-properly/36272708#comment60170773_36271742)

By lazy he means that if in your db.js file you have something like this:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/stack');
```

This is not synchronous, is just a pending connection. You can grab the connection and listen for the open event:

```
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function() {
  // we're connected!
});
```

Until this event fires, the connection is not ready.

On the other hand, mocha can handle both synchronous and asynchronous code. But since you have a callback, your code is asynchronous, so you must add the **done** callback.

```
describe('User', function() {
  describe('#save()', function() {
    it('should save without error', function(done) {
      var user = new User('Luna');
      user.save(function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        done();
      });
    });
  });
});
```

In this case the done callback is in the it section, but it works the same for all hooks.